# Python Classes: differences between inheritance and create a parent class instance inside the child (class composition)

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instance, parent-child

I have the following problem:

I have a class **A**, that only stores a big numbers of variables;
then I have 3 classes ,**B**, **C**, **D**, that inherit A to define more complex objects (different in each of the 3 classes) that depend on the set of variables defined in **A**.
Finally there is  a class **E** that has to inherit **only one** between **B**, **C**, **D**.

Since I want the flexibility to choose each time the class to include in **E** I don't want a fixed Parent name as argument of **E**. To do so, instead of inherit the class I'm creating a class instance in the `__init__()`   method (to access all the parent's methods and attributes as well); I report below the 2 different way to better express the idea.
My question is:

Is there some cons in proceeding my way, or, more in general, which are the differences between the 2 approaches?

```
class E(D):
    def __init__(self, argsE, argsPar):
        super().__init__(self, argsPar)
    ...
```

(in the example above I have to specify the parent class, which I want to give in input and not to be fixed)

```
class E:
    def __init__(self, parent, argsE, argsPar):
        if(parent=='B')
            self.parent = B(argsPar)
        if(parent=='C')
            self.parent = C(argsPar) 
        if(parent=='D')
            self.parent = D(argsPar)
      
    ...
```

Comment: As per some standard OOP patterns: Why don't you use *three* classes ``E(D)``, ``F(C)``, ``G(D)``? Why don't you pass a pre-existing *instance* of either ``B``, ``C``, ``D`` to ``E``? Do you use inheritance because these are actually subtypes (``E`` "is a" ``A``) or just code reuse?

Comment: Hi MisterMiyagi, thank you for the comment; not sure I understood it properly. Are you suggesting to create a different copy of **E** for each possible parent? I use inheritance from **A** to **B**, **C** ,**D** for coding reuse purpose (the same for **E**)

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem, so I would like to refrain from suggesting anything. However, just creating a new class for each variant seems straightforward, so in order to understand your problem I would like to know whether you have a reason not to do this straightforward thing. My personal *hunch* is that you should not use inheritance at all but just composition.

Answer (score 0):

*Since I want the flexibility to choose each time the class to include in **E** I don't want a fixed Parent name as argument of **E**.*

Then just exploit [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) to dynamically create class, consider following example

```
class A:
    pass
class B:
    pass
choice = input("Shall C inherit A xor B?")
if choice == "A":
    C = type("C", (A,), {})
elif choice == "B":
    C = type("C", (B,), {})
else:
    exit()
print(issubclass(C,A))  # True if choice was A else False
print(issubclass(C,B))  # True if choice was B else False
```

Third argument to type should be

> dictionary contains attribute and method definitions for the class
> body

In above example for brevity sake empty `dict` was used,